# Web.xml Mapping

Tags: servlets, web-applications

I want to redirect to a login page on every server start. Please help me in this .

Here's my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    MVCDemo
    
        mvc-dispatcher
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        1
    
    
        mvc-dispatcher
        *

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.webblue.controller.login.LoginController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Register</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.webblue.controller.login.LoginController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>runJsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/pages/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>runJsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
  pages/login.jsp
</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: What do you mean by redirect to login page? If you invalidate session then you would be automatically be redirected to login page.

Comment: i want that login.jsp should load by default on start up of server

Comment: When I type in http://localhost:8080/ I need to get a page in my application for e.g. http://localhost:8080/onjava/Login.jsp.

Comment: Pages mentioned under <welcome-file-list> tag should be directly under ** Web Content **.what error you are getting exactly?